# What does "commitment" mean in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am applying for university for PhD and in the funding section there is an estimation calculator that estimates: *Your Annual Commitment*

This *Annual Commitment* has a breakdown of University Composition Fee, and Total Maintenance which sum up to the *Annual Commitment*.

Now is the Annual Commitment money that I will be awarded each year, or money that I have to pay each year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the money that you will have to pay each year. Essentially, it is your "commitment" to the university. It is the yearly rate (annual).

Comment: Hello, Lisa. I was about to close-vote this question, as I assumed that this sense of 'commitment' would be found in most dictionaries. After checking, I realise that the sense is not really made all that clear. So I'll quote @MετάEd: 'A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing _why_ it is correct. Links to external resources are encouraged. Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers. For help writing a good answer, see How to Answer.'